# Fetch from array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
var arr = [{id:1, animal:'dog'}, {id:3, animal:'tiger'}, {id:2, animal:'elephant'}, {id:5, animal:'cat'}];
```

I want to fetch ids from above array of object and make another array like

```
var idArray = [1,3,2,5];
```

Please suggest a concise es6 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and pluck the `id` using an arrow function, and destructuring for the ES6 flavor:

```js
const arr = [{id:1, animal:'dog'}, {id:3, animal:'tiger'}, {id:2, animal:'elephant'}, {id:5, animal:'cat'}]

const result = arr.map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one row using `map` (it will create new array, and will put `id` from every iteration through `arr` to `idArray`), here it is:

```js
var arr = [{id:1, animal:'dog'}, {id:3, animal:'tiger'}, {id:2, animal:'elephant'}, {id:5, animal:'cat'}];

var idArray = arr.map(function(item) {return item.id});
console.log(idArray);
```

Comment: This answer is also correct, but answer from @ori is more es6.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal, I agree, ES6 solutions with arrow functions are more elegant, but not all developers are using ES6, I based on this when wrote the answer.